# Error geolocalización Ionic

Tags: android, ionic, geolocalización, programación-móvil

Ando trabajando con la [geolocalización de Ionic](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/geolocation/) y depuro el código en mi dispositivo móvil utilizando la aplicacion "[Ionic DevApp](https://ionicframework.com/docs/pro/devapp/)".

El problema que me da, es que aunque acepte los permisos para utilizar mi GPS, luego me da error de tipo `PositionError.PERMISSION_DENIED` y segun la documentación de varias webs ([Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PositionError) y [W3](https://www.w3.org/TR/geolocation-API/)) me dice que se ha denegado los permisos.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
    // onSuccess Callback
    // This method accepts a Position object, which contains the
    // current GPS coordinates
    var onSuccess = function (position) {
      alert('Latitude: ' + position.coords.latitude + '\n' +
        'Longitude: ' + position.coords.longitude + '\n' +
        'Altitude: ' + position.coords.altitude + '\n' +
        'Accuracy: ' + position.coords.accuracy + '\n' +
        'Altitude Accuracy: ' + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy + '\n' +
        'Heading: ' + position.coords.heading + '\n' +
        'Speed: ' + position.coords.speed + '\n' +
        'Timestamp: ' + position.timestamp + '\n');
    };

    // onError Callback receives a PositionError object
    function onError(error) {
      alert('code: ' + error.code + '\n' +
        'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
    }

 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, { enableHighAccuracy: true });
```

¿Por qué no me acepta los permisos?

Comment: ¿Que versión de ionic estas utilizando?

Comment: Siempre lo mantengo actualizado. Ahora es 4.1.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al parecer estas usando una implementación de la libreria de bluetooth directamente con navigator.geolocation, yo recomendaría utilizar el wraper de ionic con `npm install --save @ionic-native/geolocation` https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/geolocation/

```
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';

constructor(
  private geolocation: Geolocation
) {}

this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((response) => {
  console.log(`${response.coords.latitude} ${response.coords.longitude}`);
}).catch((error) => {
  positionError(`[geologalización]: ${error}`);
});
```

Asegúrate de que la versión que se instale corresponda a la versión de tu `@ionic-native/core`, por ejemplo algo así: `@ionic-native/core": "^4.1.2", @ionic-native/geolocation: "^4.1.2"`, también asegúrate que esté correctamente instalado el plugin de cordova `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation --variable GEOLOCATION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION="To locate you"`

Comment: He actualizadoel ionic a la misma versión. Al compilar, en el navegador Firefox me funciona bien, pero en la aplicación DevApp me da error: `Only secure origins are allowed` (https://goo.gl/Y0ZkNV). ¿Sabes cómo puedo hacerlo funcionar?

Comment: En algunos navegadores el plugin solo funciona si el host cuenta con un certificado ssl valido.

Comment: Okey. He probado generando la APK y me funciona.